# In aws ec2, sudo: apt-get: command not found error

Tags: amazon-ec2, apt-get, pycrypto

I have created an instance in amazon Linux. and I want to install python-dev. for this I was using 
sudo apt-get install python-dev  or any other package. but it throws me the command not found error.
instead of apt-get, I was used yum command but that is also not working.

I have created a flask application and I am using FileZilla and putty. I am running application (python files) using putty. I have install pycrypto but then also it is showing no module name. so somewhere I learned that I have install package python-dev. for that purpose I was using apt-get command.

Comment: What are the details of your Linux distribution? Red Hat? Ubuntu?

Comment: it is amazon Linux ami.  I am sure but I think ubuntu hai.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon linux is based on redhat distribution. So you should `yum install [package name]` instead of `apt-get'. the command`apt-get`command is used in`debian` based distribution.

You can use `yum search [package name]` to search for packages by name.

hope this helps.

Comment: thanks @arunK. I have tried that but it does not work. I had used sudo at start like sudo yum install python-dev. let me see if it works without sudo.

Comment: i suggest you use docker, so that you dont have to worry about where you are deploying, https://runnable.com/docker/python/dockerize-your-flask-application